# CSS make background-color Start in bright to dark

Tags: css, sass

im looking for way to add/create something like a filter which make the background-color start with bright color and end in dark color.

for example this picture:
[Dashboard UI | Dark & Minimal](https://dribbble.com/shots/4634988-Dashboard-UI-Dark-Minimal)
The color in the top left corner is brighter than bottom rigth corner. this is what im looking for.

**UPDATE: i also trying to show a matt color. in the picture belowe we can see the color degres are falling and making something like a ciculed lines. i want to have a clear color with out those "lines"**
[image: this picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do that:

First way (linear gradient):

`background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #55566a, #282834);`

The linear gradient function has three values the direction of the gradient the starting color and the ending color

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
div {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #55566a, #282834);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Second way (Radial gradient):

Radial gradient function also accepts the three values, first is origin of the gradient which is set to `at 0% 0%`, the first 0 is x position and second is y position. because of this gradient origin will be placed at top left corner. The second value is starting color which will be at origin and the third color is ending color which is farther away from the origin. And the 30% is the length of the color to upto which it will be visible.

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
div {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background: radial-gradient(at 0% 0%, #55566a 30%, #282834);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you man. the Radial gradient is what im looking for. can you explain the at 0% 0%, and the 30%.

Comment: Updated the answer check again

Comment: i see. is there any way to kind soft the circle line showen? kind of matt color

Comment: i will update the answer with the explain. please check it.

Comment: I believe you can do that at certain point, by modifying the length values

Comment: the update i wrote having the value of 10% and still kind ugly ("the lines")

Comment: May be by adding another color in the middle will help, you can put up as many as colors you want in the gradient. like this: https://cssgradient.io/
There are three colors loaded in it and you can see those circles are not visible, so you need to find that middle color which will eliminate the circles

Comment: thats it. thank you very much man. you are hero

Answer (score 0):

if this is exactly what you are looking for but it is possible to create color gradients with css like this:

```
linear gradient {
  background: linear gradient (blue, white);
}
```

For the diagonal gradient there is also

```
.linear-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient (to bottom right, blue, white);
}
```

Comment: is this CSS or sass? im trying to able the `background-color` on the `body{}`. how to do that?